# Is Drupal Commerce compatible with Drupal 10?

Tags: commerce, composer

Don't see this answered anywhere.
I have Drupal 10 installed, as a dev site cohabiting with a live Drupal 7 on the same server.  I don't use composer for the D7 install, but can't get it to work on the D10 install since the "php.composer.phar" (in an attempt to make modules installs and updates) command jumps to server root over which I have no control & can't update.
If commerce isn't compatible maybe I'm wasting my time.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be more of an issue of being on a compatible host server than D10.

You'll want an up to date composer too as well as being on PHP 8.1.

You should be using composer with D9/10, unless you want a world of pain.

If you are doing development, then I'd be starting on a local /staging stack.

I'd probably target D9 with CKeditor 5 to begin with.  Just to save you some hassle with dealing with compatible modules.  There's still a lot of D10 patches that need to be put into releases.

Using CKeditor 5, will enable a simpler D10 upgrade.

I'm using Commerce on D9 + composer no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Commerce 8.x-2.36 is marked as Drupal 10 compatible: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce